# How to specify availability zone when creating VM through Azure SDK

Tags: azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I'm using the [ComputeManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagementclient?view=azure-python) in Azure's Python SDK to create a virtual machine. (Specifically, `begin_start` in `VirtualMachinesOperations`, found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_07_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-compute-v2023-07-01-operations-virtualmachinesoperations-begin-start).) However, I don't see an option to specify an availability zone -- only the resouce_group_name.

Is there some way to specify the availability zone when creating the VMs?

I've gone through the docs but I can't seem to find any mention of this functionality. I do know the Azure CLI [supports this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-cli-availability-zone) -- unsure why the SDK doesn't.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a VM through Azure Python [SDK](https://medium.com/@Techie1/automate-provisioning-azure-virtual-machine-using-python-17824cd3c506) with a specified availability zone.

- Assign Azure role assignments to contributors.

**Code:**

```py
import os
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError

try:
    # Set up the Azure API clients
    subscription_id = 'subscription_id' # Update with your subscription_id
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

    # Create a new resource group
    resource_group_name = 'myresourcegroup'
    location = 'westus2'
    resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        {'location': location}
    )

    print(f'Created resource group: {resource_group_name} in location: {location}')

    # Define NIC parameters
    nic_name = 'mynic'
    vnet_name = 'myvnet'
    subnet_name = 'mysubnet'

    # Create a virtual network
    network_client.virtual_networks.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        vnet_name,
        {
            'location': location,
            'address_space': {
                'address_prefixes': ['10.0.0.0/16']
            }
        }
    ).result()

    print(f'Created virtual network: {vnet_name}')

    # Create a subnet
    network_client.subnets.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        vnet_name,
        subnet_name,
        {'address_prefix': '10.0.0.0/24'}
    ).result()

    print(f'Created subnet: {subnet_name}')

    # Create a NIC
    nic = network_client.network_interfaces.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        nic_name,
        {
            'location': location,
            'ip_configurations': [{
                'name': 'myipconfig',
                'subnet': {'id': f'/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vnet_name}/subnets/{subnet_name}'}
            }]
        }
    ).result()

    print(f'Created NIC: {nic_name}')

    # Define VM parameters
    vm_name = 'myvm'
    vm_size = 'Standard_D2_v2'  # Choose an appropriate VM size
    image_reference = {
        'publisher': 'Canonical',
        'offer': 'UbuntuServer',
        'sku': '18.04-LTS',
        'version': 'latest'
    }

    # Specify the availability zone
    availability_zone = '1'  # Change this to the desired zone (e.g., '1', '2', or '3')

    # Create a new VM with an availability zone and the created NIC
    vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        vm_name,
        {
            'location': location,
            'zones': [availability_zone],  # Specify the availability zone here
            'properties': {
                'hardwareProfile': {
                    'vmSize': vm_size
                },
                'storageProfile': {
                    'imageReference': image_reference
                },
                'osProfile': {
                    'computerName': vm_name,
                    'adminUsername': 'adminUsername',# Update with your admin username
                    'adminPassword': 'adminPassword'  # Update with your admin password
                },
                'networkProfile': {
                    'networkInterfaces': [{
                        'id': nic.id
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    )

    vm.result()

    print(f'Created VM: {vm_name} in availability zone {availability_zone}')

except HttpResponseError as ex:
    print(f"HTTP Response Error: {ex}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please stop writing custom code for questions that are just a requirement with no specifics. This is not what Stack Overflow is for